# How to send users event reminder email before 2 hours asp net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core

I'm using asp.net core 3.1 with cosmos db deployed on azure. I've build RESTful APIs. In my app users can join upcoming events by following event. Now I want to send reminder email about event before 2 hours of the event to users who've following the event. Can someone help me how can i achieve this? What logic I need to implement to send reminder email about event before 2 hours of the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need **Scheduler** to send email every periodic time, you have the following options below:

1. You can use [Quartz Scheduler](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) then get the event from db and filter the target 
    events that needs reminder email before 2 hour then send email reminder but you have 
    to configure it to run every 10 minutes for example.
2. You can create ***Windows Service*** that run on the server every your target time.
3. You can use [Windows ask Scheduler](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10) (fastest and easy way), it is built in on windows all you have to do is create console application to get target event and point the  windows task Scheduler to that exe (console application).

Comment: Should i run it every hour? every minute? I'm confused about it.

Comment: That depends on your application events data , you can specify the running cycle by the cases that event happens for example , lets say the events usually  happens between 5pm-6pm then you have to run it between 2pm-3pm daily .

Comment: What if event happens any time within 24hrs ?

Comment: then you have to schedule it every "your specific time" daily , i suggest run it every 30 minutes and send every event that requires email before 2 hour and (2 and 30 minutes) to make sure that you have sent to every event attendee or run it every 5 minutes and send every event that requires email before 2 hour and before (2 and 5 minutes)

Comment: Thanks for guidance.

Comment: you're welcome if you wanna any help with the Scheduler don't hesitate.

Comment: OK God bless you.

Comment: What about hosted services and worker service for doing this in asp.net core?

Comment: You can use any of them there are advantages and disadvantages for each of the options that i mentioned and you mentioned you have to read about the differences. if you used windows service or windows task scheduler it will be isolated from your application  as a standalone project you can control it without worries about your application but if you used hosted services and worker service they will work as background service, they will start with the application and stops with the application stops , they will be related to your web application.

Comment: Another difference that if you used windows service or task scheduler you will configure it using these tools lets say if you have windows service you can go to services then start or restart the service , also task scheduler has tool to configure your scheduler periodic , but hosted services  and worker services you have to configure every thing in your code.

Comment: Thanks for detail info very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is very vague and will likely be closed but anyways.  What you need is some kind of worker process that kicks in on a schedule, lets say every hour, query the database, find if there are reminders to send and send them or delegate them to another worker who's sole responsibility is sending emails.  There are many ways to achieve that in Azure and you'll have to do some research and proof of concepts to find the one that suits your system.  Here are some services that can run on a schedule:

- If you use a Web App, you can add a Web Job.
- Azure Function
- Logic App

Comment: Should i run it every hour? every minute? I'm confused about it.